# I want to use a stringtokenizer to store strings into an object User array but get an error message

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am getting an error that says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Members. init (Members.java:23) at Main.main(Main.java:9)
And what I'm trying to do is to use StringTokenizer to store strings from a file input into and object array.

In main, line 9 just initiates the object and the code is: Members members = new Members("users.txt");

Line 23 is class Members is: users[nm].setId(st.nextToken());

I can't figure out what the error is.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Members {
int nm = 0; //Number of members
User [] users = new User[100]; //Assuming max 
number of user is 100
StringTokenizer st;
Scanner s1;
File f1;
String var1; //this string determines if it a standard or admin user;
String var2;

public Members(String fn) throws FileNotFoundException {
    f1 = new File(fn);
    s1 = new Scanner(f1);

    while(s1.hasNext()) {
        //System.out.println("true");
        st = new StringTokenizer(s1.nextLine(),"/");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            //System.out.print(((String)st.nextToken()));
            users[nm].setId(st.nextToken());
            users[nm].setPw(st.nextToken());
            var1 = st.nextToken();
            users[nm].setFn(st.nextToken());
            users[nm].setLn(st.nextToken());
            users[nm].setEmail(st.nextToken());
            //System.out.print(st.nextToken() + " ");
            if(var1.equals("Admin")) {
                users[nm].setAdmin(true);
                ((Admin)users[nm]).setRank(st.nextToken());
            }
            if(var1.equals("Standard")) {
                users[nm].setStandard(true);
                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    ((Standard)users[nm]).addCar(st.nextToken());
                }

            }
        }

        nm++;

        System.out.println();
    }

    s1.close();
    System.out.println("Number of members: " + nm);
}
```

Comment: You can only call st.nextToken() once after you have called st.hasMoreToken(). If you can give me a sample of how your one line looks like, I can help you a regex solution that would be cake walk for you to solve your problem.

Comment: seems your Users objects are null. populate the array with a User object and thn set something.

Comment: dkim/1234/Admin/Carlos/Guerra/admin@carmax.com/dealer
app123/6364.dd3K/Standard/Jackson/James/J88@gmail.com/0
hukkz993/3!7A2dss/Standard/Gonzalez/Mike/MH332@yahoo.com/0
apple12/3W2i.d2/Admin/Kim/Dongchul/dkim@carmax.com/business manager
23fasd/39SD.jd/Standard//Cantu/Roy/kcantu02@hotmail.com/2/AB234KL34/FF2HHKL94

Comment: That is how my users.txt looks and what I'm trying to use the tokenizer for

Comment: creating an array is mostly equivalent to creating (a lot of) variables that can hold some object, no instance of that object will be created, it's just a *placeholder*. (like `String var1;` does not create any string, just a variable for one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an array that can hold `Users`, but as far as I can tell you aren't creating any instances of `User`. When you first try to reference `users[nm]` its value is going to be `null`.

You could do something like this:

```
users[nm] = new User();
users[nm].setId(st.nextToken());
```

Answer (score 0):

The main culprit is `User [] users = new User[100]; //Assuming max`

This is creating a array of size 100 only. Not Creating any object. You are setting `Id` to a null object. Before setting the Id you have to initialize your user object.